# AngularJS + Bootstrap - Validating Text Box - how to show validation feedback only after the user has entered some data?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am doing some validation on text boxes. Once the user enters a valid input, the text box should become green and a tick mark should appear at the rightmost corner. Similarly, if the user has entered an invalid data, text box should become red and a cross should appear instead.

For this, I'm using bootstrap's '`has-error has-feedback'` and `'has-success has-feedback'` css classes.

My problem is that the textbox is green and has a tick even when the page is loaded for the first time. I need the validation feedback to appear only after the user has entered an input. And the same applies when the form is used to edit the existing records. How can I achieve this ?  (I'm not sure if I could use `$dirty` and '$pristine` to solve this problem)

Below is my Markup.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="(Form.emailAddress.$valid) ? 'has-success has-feedback': 'has-error has-feedback'">
    <label for="emailAddress">Email address</label>
    <span ng-show="!Form.emailAddress.$valid">Please enter a valid address</span>

    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailAddress" name="emailAddress" ng-model="Data.emailAddress" ng-pattern="validationPattern" ng-maxlength="20">

    <span ng-show="Form.emailAddress.$valid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></span>
    <span ng-show="!Form.emailAddress.$valid" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove  form-control-feedback"></span>
</div>
```

A few more questions regarding this topic.

I would like to check the maxlength of the email as well, and if it exceeds 20, I would want to show a different message. I tried Form.emailAddress.$maxlength but couldn't get it working. Does it maxlength work on 'email' types as well ?

How can I show the feedback after the user moves to the next textbox instead of showing it while typing ? May be something similar to jquery's 'focusout()'.

I've used a validation pattern in the controller because email is not a required field, but when entered it has to be valid. Could I please know if there are better ways than doing this ?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you try (Form.emailAddress.$valid && Form.emailAddress.$dirty) so the field is only green if it is dirty and valid?

Comment: Yes. I tried ng-class="(contactDetailsForm.emailAddress.$valid) && contactDetailsForm.emailAddress.$dirty ? 'has-success has-feedback': 'has-error has-feedback'" but then the textbox becomes red by default when the page is loaded.

Comment: You need two separate checks. $valid && $dirty to check for green and a separate $invalid && $dirty to check for red.

Comment: So, Should I use to ternary operations with in ng-class ? Could you please show it with an example ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use $valid && $dirty for green and in a separate check, use $invalid and $dirty for red.

Here's an example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/k8X5NSeUrBb2nqA9yD9F

```
<form name="myform">
  Valid: {{myform.myinput.$valid}}<br/>
  Dirty: {{myform.myinput.$dirty}}<br/>
  <input type="text" 
         name="myinput" 
         required 
         ng-model="myvalue" 
         ng-class="{'has-success has-feedback': \
                     myform.myinput.$valid && myform.myinput.$dirty, \
                    'has-error has-feedback': \
                     myform.myinput.$invalid && myform.myinput.$dirty}"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. your answer looks very promising. I'll give it a go. Does $invalid and $error.maxlength work on input type ="email" as well ?

Comment: If you peek at the Angular code, the email input type extends the text input type.  So, everything that works on a text input should work on an email input.